# filtering a query with parse - swift2

Tags: parse-platform, swift2

I'm trying to query with multiple conditions in parse, for example, I only entered an occupation and left all the other fields empty, and hit the search button. It will query all the occupation data but after that are the other data which isn't relevant to the filter.

How can I limit the results based on the users filtered search.

the problem is that my query below returns all the data from parse,

```
    let occupationQuery = PFQuery(className: "JobPost")
    occupationQuery.whereKey("occupation", containsString: occupationLabel.text)

    let genderQuery = PFQuery(className: "JobPost")
    genderQuery.whereKey("gender", containsString: genderLabel.text)

    let workExperienceQuery = PFQuery(className: "JobPost")
    workExperienceQuery.whereKey("workExperience", containsString: workExperienceLabel.text)

    let employmentStatusQuery = PFQuery(className: "JobPost")
    employmentStatusQuery.whereKey("employerStatus", containsString: employmentLabel.text)

    let nationalityQuery = PFQuery(className: "JobPost")
    nationalityQuery.whereKey("nationality", containsString: nationalityLabel.text)

    let finalQuery = PFQuery.orQueryWithSubqueries([occupationQuery, genderQuery, workExperienceQuery, employmentStatusQuery, nationalityQuery])

    finalQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (results: [AnyObject]?, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil{
            let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil)
            myAlert.addAction(okAction)
            self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

            return
        }

        if let objects = results as? [PFObject] {
            self.searchResults.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
                print(objects)
            print(objects)

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

seems like I was using a wrong function, change containString to equalTo.

```
employmentStatusQuery.whereKey("employerStatus", equalTo:
employmentLabel.text!)
```